# What is ISCJS.cl? Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: jquery

So, long story short, I don't know much JS or jQuery at all. I have a friend, however, that does. This sounds ridiculous, but he wrote me this bit of code before leaving the country on a tour of Europe and I'm getting an Uncaught ReferenceError. I can't get a hold of him, because he's gone now, and I need to get this working. I'm getting the error:

**Uncaught ReferenceErorr: ISCJS is not defined**

And here's the code:

```
 function selectNextChoice(option, choice) {
        ISCJS.cl('init: selectNextChoice( option, ' + choice + ' )');
        if (choice > 3) {
            return;
        }
        if ($choices.find('#Choice' + choice + ' .option').length ==
            0) {
            $clone = option.clone();
            if ('Undecided' != option.data('option')) {
                option.data({
                    'selected': true,
                    'number': choice
                }).addClass('selected');
                option.find('> .overlay').html(choice);
                $clone[0].setAttribute('draggable', false);
            }
            $choices.find('#Choice' + choice)[0].setAttribute(
                'data-choice', option.data('option'));
            $('#Selection' + choice).val(option.data('option'));
            $choices.find('#Choice' + choice).css('border-color',
                'transparent').html($clone).append(
                '<span class="exit fa fa-times"></span>');
        } else {
            choice++;
            selectNextChoice(option, choice);
        }
    }
```

I really don't know what I'm doing. I've learned CSS, HTML, and PHP, but am just starting to learn JS and jQuery, so I'm lost. Thanks for any help!

Comment: This maybe? https://github.com/TheGiftsProject/iscjs

Comment: Like I said, I don't know much at all. I looked/searched through the files there and was unable to find anything within the code defined as ISCJS. So, now I'm really confused, cause that seems like that'd be it.

Comment: Did @Bongani's answer help you figure it out?

Comment: No, I've had to abandon my friends code. I'm past due at the moment and trying to learn it and figure something out myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this before using ISCJS:

```
if(typeof ISCJS !== "undefined"){
   ISCJS.cl('init: selectNextChoice( option, ' + choice + ' )');

} else {
   console.log("ERROR: ISCJS is not defined");

}
```

If you get an error message "ERROR: ISCJS is not defined" on the console then ISCJS is not properly defined, that is, you did not initialise ISCJS inside the code.